# Simple JS Arrow Function: Missing Parenthesis After Argument List: Why?

Tags: javascript

This simple javascript arrow function results in a parser error. The syntax seems consistent with all the examples I've seen. What is the syntax error and how do I correct it?

```
var things = [];
things.push("a");
var containsA = things.some(t => t === "a");
```

The error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: It works on latest Firefox Nightly.

Comment: @Oriol Interesting. I have only tested in Chrome latest and jsfiddle. Would it be easy for you to check in Chrome? Maybe it's browser-specific.

Comment: I think currently only Firefox supports arrow functions.

Comment: @Oriol I think you are correct. I was able to confirm that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

If you want to add as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces a valid [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
t => t === "a"
```

However, arrow functions are an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 6 proposal, which currently is still a draft. Therefore, not all browsers have implemented them yet.

Among the major ones, only Firefox has. If you attempt to use them on Chrome, you will get an error.

Comment: Answer confirmed here (at time of writing): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Currently `Arrow Functions` are supported by `FireFox` only.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility):

[image: Browser Compatibility for Arrow Functions]